# Using a Regex in the URI of a Mongrel Handler

Tags: ruby, regex, http, handler, mongrel

I'm currently using Mongrel to develop a custom web application project.

I would like Mongrel to use a defined Http Handler based on a regular expression. For example, everytime someone calls a url like http://test/bla1.js or http://test/bla2.js the same Http handler is called to manage the request.

My code so far looks a like that:

```
http_server = Mongrel::Configurator.new :host => config.get("http_host") do
  listener :port => config.get("http_port") do

    uri Regexp.escape("/[a-z0-9]+.js"), :handler => BLAH::CustomHandler.new
    uri '/ui/public', :handler => Mongrel::DirHandler.new("#{$d}/public/")
    uri '/favicon', :handler => Mongrel::Error404Handler.new('')

    trap("INT") { stop }
    run
  end
end
```

As you can see, I am trying to use a regex instead of a string here:

```
 uri Regexp.escape("/[a-z0-9]+.js"), :handler => BLAH::CustomHandler.new
```

but that does not work. Any solution?

Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject new code into part of Mongrel's `URIClassifier`, which is otherwise blissfully unaware of regular expression URIs.

Below is one way of doing just that:

```
#
# Must do the following BEFORE Mongrel::Configurator.new
#  Augment some of the key methods in Mongrel::URIClassifier
#  See lib/ruby/gems/XXX/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/uri_classifier.rb
#
Mongrel::URIClassifier.class_eval <<-EOS, __FILE__, __LINE__
  # Save original methods
  alias_method :register_without_regexp, :register
  alias_method :unregister_without_regexp, :unregister
  alias_method :resolve_without_regexp, :resolve

  def register(uri, handler)
    if uri.is_a?(Regexp)
      unless (@regexp_handlers ||= []).any? { |(re,h)| re==uri ? h.concat(handler) : false }
        @regexp_handlers << [ uri, handler ]
      end
    else
      # Original behaviour
      register_without_regexp(uri, handler)
    end
  end

  def unregister(uri)
    if uri.is_a?(Regexp)
      raise Mongrel::URIClassifier::RegistrationError, "\#{uri.inspect} was not registered" unless (@regexp_handlers ||= []).reject! { |(re,h)| re==uri }
    else
      # Original behaviour
      unregister_without_regexp(uri)
    end
  end

  def resolve(request_uri)
    # Try original behaviour FIRST
    result = resolve_without_regexp(request_uri)
    # If a match is not found with non-regexp URIs, try regexp
    if result[0].blank?
      (@regexp_handlers ||= []).any? { |(re,h)| (m = re.match(request_uri)) ? (result = [ m.pre_match + m.to_s, (m.to_s == Mongrel::Const::SLASH ? request_uri : m.post_match), h ]) : false }
    end
    result
  end
EOS

http_server = Mongrel::Configurator.new :host => config.get("http_host") do 
  listener :port => config.get("http_port") do 

    # Can pass a regular expression as URI
    #  (URI must be of type Regexp, no escaping please!)
    # Regular expression can match any part of an URL, start with "^/..." to
    #  anchor match at URI beginning.
    # The way this is implemented, regexp matches are only evaluated AFTER
    #  all non-regexp matches have failed (mostly for performance reasons.)
    # Also, for regexp URIs, the :in_front is ignored; adding multiple handlers
    #  to the same URI regexp behaves as if :in_front => false
    uri /^[a-z0-9]+.js/, :handler => BLAH::CustomHandler.new 

    uri '/ui/public', :handler => Mongrel::DirHandler.new("#{$d}/public/") 
    uri '/favicon', :handler => Mongrel::Error404Handler.new('') 

    trap("INT") { stop } 
    run 
  end 
end
```

Seems to work just fine with Mongrel 1.1.5.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider creating a [Rack application](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) instead. Rack is:

- **the** standard for Ruby web applications
- used internally by all popular Ruby web frameworks ([Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html), [Merb](http://brainspl.at/articles/2008/02/16/so-merb-core-is-built-on-rack-you-say-why-should-i-care), [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/2009/01/18/sinatra-0.9.0.html), [Camping](http://www.mail-archive.com/camping-list@rubyforge.org/msg00492.html), [Ramaze](http://wiki.ramaze.net/Principles), ...)
- much easier to extend
- ready to be run on **any** application server (Mongrel, Webrick, Thin, Passenger, ...)

Rack has a URL mapping DSL, [Rack::Builder](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Builder.html), which allows you to map different Rack applications to particular URL prefixes. You typically save it as `config.ru`, and run it with `rackup`.

Unfortunately, it does not allow regular expressions either. But because of the simplicity of Rack, it is really easy to write an "application" (a `lambda`, actually) that will call the proper app if the URL matches a certain regex.

Based on your example, your `config.ru` may look something like this:

```
require "my_custom_rack_app" # Whatever provides your MyCustomRackApp.

js_handler = MyCustomRackApp.new

default_handlers = Rack::Builder.new do
  map "/public" do
    run Rack::Directory.new("my_dir/public")
  end

  # Uncomment this to replace Rack::Builder's 404 handler with your own:
  # map "/" do
  #   run lambda { |env|
  #     [404, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["My 404 response"]]
  #   }
  # end
end

run lambda { |env|
  if env["PATH_INFO"] =~ %r{/[a-z0-9]+\.js}
    js_handler.call(env)
  else
    default_handlers.call(env)
  end
}
```

Next, run your Rack app on the command line:

```
% rackup
```

If you have mongrel installed, it will be started on port 9292. **Done!**